# Why insert into the table is causing conflicts with already existing primary keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.campaign_result
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('campaign_result_id_seq'::regclass),
    state result_state NOT NULL DEFAULT 'processing'::result_state,
    data json NOT NULL,
    response json,
    act result_action NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none'::result_action,
    message character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    campaign_id uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),

    CONSTRAINT campaign_result_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),

    CONSTRAINT campaign_result_campaign_id_fkey 
        FOREIGN KEY (campaign_id)
        REFERENCES public.campaign (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

This table has almost 1200 entries, but when I do inserts into it, I get this error:

> Failed due to duplicate key value violates unique constraint "campaign_result_pkey"
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(137) already exists.

This is how I am inserting in it:

```
def campaing_result_insert(item, messsage, campaign_id):
    conn = connect_db()
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO campaign_result(data, Campaign_id, message) VALUES (%s::json, %s, %s) RETURNING id, data;""",
                    (item, campaign_id, messsage))

        return cur.fetchone()
```

That's really a weird issue. What is the problem?

Comment: If you tring to insart new values, just make ID auto increment: ID  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
This aproach allow you insert data without ID. It will be generated automaticaly.

Comment: its already sequential.

Comment: the problem is if there is already 1200 entries, why today the table start sequential primary key from 100?

Comment: The sequence `campaign_result_id_seq` is generating values for `id` that already exist in the table. The probable cause is that prior inserts explicitly included the `id` column, so the sequence was not incremented. Set the sequence's last value to something greater than the highest `id` value in the table.

Comment: @JohnH How can I do?

Comment: Actually I moved this data from other database, and inserted into new one(the current) one. It's not added with id, it's auto incremented from the start.

Comment: Seems like the current value of `campaign_result_id_seq` is colliding with existing data. Maybe that sequence is "out of sequence".

Comment: Use `id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` and forget about sequences.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks, But How do I fix this now? is there a way to change the value of `campaign_result_id_seq`?

Comment: When there are already 1200 records and your sequence started using number 1 for the first record, someone messed up with your sequence: Key (id)=(137) would never be used again. Find the name of your sequence and set it to a high enough number, that is no used: `SELECT setval('campaign_result_id_seq', 2000);`. And make sure nobody can change the setting manually, like this

Comment: @FrankHeikens make sense. How do I fix this?

Comment: `alter sequence campaign_result_id_seq restart with 9999` ? Replace 9999 with the max existing value + 1.

Comment: @TheImpaler, using `id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` eliminates the explicit `DEFAULT nextval`: sequences are still used and the OP's issue could still occur. The same is true if `SERIAL` is the type instead of `INTEGER`. Declaring `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` does protect against inadvertently inserting explicit ID values since doing so would require adding `OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE` to the `INSERT` command.

Answer (score 2):

The following query synchronizes the sequence with the table ID values:

```
SELECT SETVAL('campaign_result_id_seq', t.max_id)
  FROM campaign_result_id_seq s
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT max(id) AS max_id
                FROM campaign_result) t
 WHERE s.last_value < t.max_id;
```

I've often used this approach when bulk loading data for testing.

Answer (score 0):

As you guys helped in the comments change the value for `campaign_result_id_seq` was simple. I used pgadmin4 followed these steps to change its value
1

1. Go to Sequences in your database
2. Right click on the *_id_seq, in my case it was `campaign_result_id_seq` got to properties
3. Go to `Definition` tab and change the current value.

[image]